# how to set font type to webview

Tags: android, html, fonts, webview

I have found many question to set font type to webview.I have tried i can't able to fix.

I have 10 html file in my assest folder. In swipe im displaying one by one in webview, Till this its works fine, now i need on button click change font type of that(for all html page which im loading 10 files). How can i change font type of my html displaying in webview.

1st way

```
  mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            WebSettings webSettings = mainContent.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mainContent.requestFocusFromTouch();
            mainContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            mainContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            mainContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+filename.get(position));
       Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf"); 
            webSettings.setFixedFontFamily(font);
            webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(20);
```

2nd way

I have get the content of html and i have passed into a string, i can't able to pass into it, if the content passed correctly this will work.

```
   mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            WebSettings webSettings = mainContent.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mainContent.requestFocusFromTouch();
            mainContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            mainContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+filename.get(position));
            mainContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    mainContent.setWebViewClient(null);    
           mainContent.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<div>'+document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML+'</div>');");
                     String pish = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/Kelvetica.ttf\")}body {font-family: MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
                     String pas = "</body></html>";     
                     String myHtmlString = pish + page + pas;   // here i can't able to get the `page`
                     mainContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

and in my activity

```
  class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void processHTML(final String html) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     Spanned page = Html.fromHtml(html);
                     System.out.println("content"+page);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

i need to pass this `page` into above code

3rd way

```
  mainContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            WebSettings webSettings = mainContent.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mainContent.requestFocusFromTouch();
            mainContent.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT"); 
           mainContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+filename.get(position));
            mainContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    mainContent.setWebViewClient(null);
                    mainContent.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { var s=document.createElement('style');s.innerHTML ="
                                + " '@font-face{font-family:ZawGyi-One;src:url('file:///android_asset/fonts/zeroesthree.ttf');}"
                                + "body,div,h1,h2,h3,input,textarea{font-family:ZawGyi-One! important;}';"
                                + "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily = \"ZawGyi-One\"})()");
                }
            });
```

I have tried like this. I can't able to change the fonttype. Any one have idea please share it. I'm working on this problem for past two days.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in two way

1. If your button is part of html then you can call a JavaScript function on click event
2. Using Android button you can call a JavaScript function that will update font family

Here is example :
CSS font_first.css:

```
.box_heading{
        width:340px;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:#000;
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:normal;
        margin-top:14px;
        float:left;
        text-transform:uppercase;}
```

Html: [index.html](http://pastie.org/9396194)

If you are doing this with second method you just need to call `changeFont()` from android webview for this you have to call `mainContent.loadUrl("javascript:changeFont()")`

**EDIT** 
If so you can try this : `myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('navigationText')style.fontFamily ='"+fontName+"');`

Comment: i have a static files, im getting it from db and showing in webview using position..

Comment: yes its worked..  slight change like this.. `mainContent.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('maindiv').style.fontFamily = 'courier';");` you should the `fontname` in single quotes @JaiSoni

Comment: @MakeitSimple Great :)

Comment: cool... Thanks a lot bro.. yesterday eve itself i have completed.. Thanks a Lot..... :)